# Text area for progress bar

Tags: user-interface, text, javafx, progress-bar

I would like to add a text area where the user can see some information that i can see in the console while the progress bar is updating.

How can i add the text area ?

Here is a sample of the code I have used to make the progress bar. Can i add below the progress bar the text area which should fill while computations are mare?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class ProgressDialogExample extends Application {
static int option = 0;
static ProgressForm pForm = new ProgressForm();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button startButton = new Button("Start");
    startButton.setOnAction(e -> {

        // In real life this task would do something useful and return
        // some meaningful result:
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        updateProgress(i, 10);
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                    updateProgress(10, 10);
                    return null;
                }
            };

            // binds progress of progress bars to progress of task:
            pForm.activateProgressBar(task);

            // in real life this method would get the result of the task
            // and update the UI based on its value:
            task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                startButton.setDisable(false);
            });

            startButton.setDisable(true);
            pForm.getDialogStage().show();

            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
        });

    StackPane root = new StackPane(startButton);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

private int closeWindow() {
    return option;
}

private static void setCloseWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    option = 1;
}

public static class ProgressForm {
    private final Stage dialogStage;
    private final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    private final ProgressIndicator pin = new ProgressIndicator();

    public ProgressForm() {
        dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        // dialogStage.setResizable(false);
        // dialogStage.setWidth(400);
        // dialogStage.setHeight(300);
        // final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        final Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        exitButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                pForm.getDialogStage().close();
                setCloseWindow();
            }
        });
        // PROGRESS BAR

        pb.setProgress(-1F);
        pin.setProgress(-1F);

        final HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(5);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(pb, pin,  exitButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb);

        dialogStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public void activateProgressBar(final Task<?> task) {
        pb.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        pin.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        dialogStage.show();
    }

    public Stage getDialogStage() {
        return dialogStage;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) `Labelled` before use `Label` instead of the Text `Node` you want to use and write your text when you want to, when you want to show your Progressbars do

```
Label.setGraphic(myprogressbarNode);
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

> I would like to add a text area where the user can see some information that i can see in the console while the progress bar is updating... Can i add below the progress bar the text area which should fill while computations are mare?

and i gave you a solution to it.

suppose you have your `ProgressBar` `pb`; and you are adding your ProgressBar to a `StackPane` you do not have to add the `ProgressBar` directly but rather add your `Text` which you will implement that by `Label` so presume your `Label` is `lb` this is how your code will look like

```
StackPane sp; // parent
ProgressBar pb; // progress indicator
Lable lb; // my text area

sp.getChildren().add(lb);// i have added the text area
lb.setGraphic(pb); we have added the progressbar to the text area
lb.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.***);//the *** represents the position you want your graphic
//whether top or left or bottom
//now you are done, your pb will show aligned to your lb, and be updated
//if you want to show text lb.setText("your text");
```

how implicit is this? :-)

Comment: can you be a little bit more explicit? I don't understand the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a listener to the task's messageProperty that will append the text to a TextArea whenever it is changed.

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();

public void activateTextArea(final Task<?> task) {
    task.messageProperty().addListener((property, oldValue, newValue) -> {
         ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\n" + newValue);
    });
}
```

Then put something like this inside the task:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           updateProgress(i, 10);
           updateMessage((i*10) + "% done");
           Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        updateProgress(10, 10);
        updateMessage("All done!");
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it gives me an error for property and new value

Comment: Just noticed a typo in the code I posted. Try putting a comma between oldValue and newValue

Comment: still, when I add "ta" to a GridPane i get an error because I have to declare ta as static. Is there any solution?